# What anime is the clip mentioned below from?

Tags: story-identification, anime

Does anyone know what anime the girl at 3:00 is from?

Comment: Haha I was about to say someone asked the same in the video comments but it appears to be yourself.

Comment: Side note, don't be too concerned on the downvotes. They're just personal opinions. There are some people who are opposed to the "who's this one person in the video" because it doesn't give them much text to search on, and reverse image searches are highly dependent on getting a definitive screenshot, often difficult due to smearing/blurring in the video.

Answer (score 4):

Doing a reverse image search, it looks to be [Azaka Kokutou](https://www.anisearch.com/character/1946,azaka-kokutou) from [Kara no Kyoukai](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Kara_no_Kyoukai).

[image: Screenshot from video - Lightskinned girl in blue dress and dark hair has arms thrust back with a corona of energy around them, approaching three projectiles in a dark room]

[image: Screenshot from character page - Lightskinned girl in blue dress and dark hair is emitting an arc of green energy between her hands that is slewing to the left of the viewer]

Comment: Good find. Nicely done. And an explanation of how you found it is always a good sight to see.